# Imprecise multiplication Text/Integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing a decimal (pattern <4 digits>.<10 digits>) stored as text (VARCHAR)

```
`COST_VALUE` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
```

When i execute a script with multiplication of this value cast as DOUBLE by a COUNT as bellow:

```
Select ... count(OTHER_ATTR) as QUANTITY, record.COST_VALUE as COST, CAST(techno.COST_VALUE AS DOUBLE) * count(OTHER_ATTR)) as TOTAL
```

I get a wrong result in some fields (indeed, a result not precise) as bellow:

[image]

The simple multiplication isn't precise too:

```
record.COST_VALUE * count(OTHER_ATTR)) as TOTAL
```

The DECIMAL (CAST(techno.COST_VALUE AS DECIMAL) returns the result as Integer (not fraction)

[image]

How can i get the EXACT result without casting with a limited value like CAST(techno.COST_VALUE AS DOUBLE(10, 2)) ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: *"How can i get the EXACT result without casting"* [DOUBLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) is a Floating-Point Type (Approximate Value), you should be using [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) which is a Fixed-Point Type (Exact Value)

Comment: Also what is the datatype of `techno.COST_VALUE` ? Ideally you should post a `CREATE TABLE` statement for this table use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and also provide some example data for it see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) if you want better comments or answers.

Comment: *"How can i get the EXACT result without casting with a limited value like CAST(techno.COST_VALUE AS DOUBLE(10, 2)) ?"*  Most likely you can get away with no `CAST()` in MySQL  because  MySQL is loose typed database.. Using `(techno.COST_VALUE  * COUNT(DISTINCT r.ID)) as TOTAL`  should work just fine.

Comment: The simple multiplication isn't precise too, thak you @RaymondNijland for your remarks !

Comment: *"The simple multiplication isn't precise too"* i very much doubt that as MySQL uses [Precision Math](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math.html) where possible.. I advice you to to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results what way we can make better answers.

Comment: For precise result use precise datatype... decimal.